# issue with generating sitemap for the web app in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sitemap

I need to generate the sitemap.xml file for the web app .I went through this article on  https://www.amitsn.com/blog/how-to-generate-a-sitemap-for-your-react-website-with-dynamic-content  and generate the .xml file

Here are the routes for which I want to generate the xml file.

```
   <Route

           path ="/cricket/tournament/:id/standings"

           />
          <Route
            path="/cricket/:description/:id"

          />

          <Route
            path="/football/:description/:id"

          />
```

Now the issue is that the xml file generated comes this way .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mobile="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-mobile/1.0" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
<url> <loc>https://xyz.io/</loc> </url>
<url> <loc>https://xyz.io/cricket/tournament/:id/standings</loc> </url>
<url> <loc>https://xyz.io/cricket/:description/:id</loc> </url>
<url> <loc>https://xyz.io/football/:description/:id</loc> </url>
</urlset>
```

and in google console webmasters 
https://xyz.io/cricket/tournament/:id/standings.xml
 this link won't open so how to get dynamic urls .

Comment: What have you tried already? What is _your_ equivalent of the tutorial's `generateSitemap()` function?

Comment: I gave the url of my website to build .xml file .

Comment: The generator you're using is not going to crawl your site for you, you have to programmatically tell it what to do to populate the `:id` part of the sitemap. 

If you look at the section "Step 5 - Adding dynamic paths to your sitemap.xml" they're showing you how to do this by connecting to your own API. You need to write an equivalent to this.